# PGFplots: using the table feature

Tags: pgfplots

I have 4 sets of data that all have the same t values (x axis).  Can all list be read in at once?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table{
     t  actual  measured  est Q = 0.01  est Q = 0.1
    .1  .1     .2107      .2107         .2107
    .2  .2     .5954      .4122         .4671
    .3  .3     .5940      .4820         .5464
    .4  .4     .4758      .4800         .5027
    .5  .5     .3183      .4207         .3661
    .6  .6     .4060      .4131         .3833
    }
\end{axis}
\end{document}
```

Can 4 lines be read in like this?  If so, how can I differentiate them with 4 different markers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely:

[image: screenshot]

The idea is to read the data into a macro (called `\mydata` in the code below), and then you can use, for example:

```
  \addplot table[x=t,y=actual]{\mydata};
```

and specify the `x` and `y` as you wish.

Note that if you want to use spaces in the column names, then you need to enclose them in braces; for example, you'll note that I used `{est Q = 0.1}` in both the column name and the `addplot` command.

Here's a complete MWE that demonstrates the idea.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
t  actual  measured  {est Q = 0.01}  {est Q = 0.1}
    .1  .1     .2107      .2107         .2107
    .2  .2     .5954      .4122         .4671
    .3  .3     .5940      .4820         .5464
    .4  .4     .4758      .4800         .5027
    .5  .5     .3183      .4207         .3661
    .6  .6     .4060      .4131         .3833
    }\mydata
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot table[x=t,y=actual]{\mydata};
  \addplot table[x=t,y=measured]{\mydata};
  \addplot table[x=t,y={est Q = 0.01}]{\mydata};
  \addplot table[x=t,y={est Q = 0.1}]{\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @dustin you'll have to change the `pgfplotstableread` command to include the `comma`, not the `addplot` command. But, yes, overall, it will work

Comment: @dustin use commas to separate every element in every row